# Socket 1700 Mainboard for Windows Server

Tags: motherboard, server, windows

We have a small server with Windows Server 2016. It previously run on AMD Ryzen.

We have upgraded the hardware to: i5-13600 on ASUS Prime B760-PLUS

Problem: Modern Mainboards (any Socket 1700 for instance) seem to lack Windows Server compatible Drivers.

We have managed to install some drivers manually using inf Files.

However, Graphic Driver, RAID-Controller, a PCI-Communication controller and another unknown device still can not be installed.

Question: Is there any way to install all drivers for this Mainboard on Windows Server 2016?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking

Comment: What drivers specifically have you had trouble installing?